# Selenium-Python --How do I fetch particular value from table and verify that value

Tags: python

I am working on SEARCH functionality where I have table with 5 columns and 10 rows. I am searching a particular value "ACCEPTED" from column no 4(Status column). If column 4 have some other value than 'ACCEPTED' than checked the value of column 1 and column 5  in same row whether it contains the word "ACCEPTED". Let say column 4 have the value 'Rejected' but column 5 have the file name 'Accepted Valid File', assertion will pass. And if all 10 rows contain the word 'Accepted' in at-least one column than the testcase will pass.

In short check all 10 rows and if at least one of column have word "ACCEPTED" than the testcase is pass otherwise fail.

code is here:

```
class FileStatusPage(BaseDriver,softest.TestCase):
     def clickOnSearchIcon(self):
            searchIcon = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//mat-icon[normalize-space()='search']")
            searchIcon.click()
            table_xpath = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//tbody[@class='mdc-data-table__content']")
            rows = table_xpath.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "tr")
            print(len(rows)) # it displays 10
            for row in rows:
                col = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")[3]
                print(col.text) # it displays all 10 values of column 4
                self.soft_assert(self.assertEqual, 'ACCEPTED', col.text)
            self.assert_all()
```

The above code displays correct value of each cell of column 4.(Columns are 0 to 4)
In above code soft assertion is also not working. Any help will be appreciated.